# If $Q*P$ is constant, why is $\frac{\Delta Q/Q}{\Delta P / P}$ constant?

Tags: calculus, economics

The title says it all; I don't quite get why $Q*P$ being constant implies that $\frac{\Delta Q/Q}{\Delta P / P}$ is constant. Or does it?

This is about iso-elastic demand curves - why is it that $Q*P=const.$ implies that $\frac{\Delta Q/Q}{\Delta P / P} = -1$?

$Q$ and $R$ are both elements of $\mathbb{R}_+$, respectively.

Comment: You need to provide more context.

Comment: I tried to add some context -- is that sufficient? I think the answer is actually pretty trivial, but I don't see it. @BokaPeer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, in mathematics that should be $ \dfrac{dQ/Q}{dP/P} $ not $\dfrac{\Delta Q/Q}{\Delta P/P}$: $\Delta Q$ and $\Delta P$ would indicate finite changes, which would not give a constant result, while $dQ$ and $dP$ are [differentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function). Economics may use different notation.

You get it from differentiating: if $PQ$ is constant,
$$ 0 = d(PQ) = Q\; dP + P \; dQ $$

so $$ \frac{dQ}{Q} = - \frac{dP}{P} $$

Comment: Thanks! `Economics may use different notation.` No, I think that's rather foolish me not knowing the difference. Got it.

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) two ways to approach this.  In either case, suppose
$$  P \cdot Q = k  $$
for some nonzero constant $k$.

Method 1:

Recall "[logarithmic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_differentiation)".  And notice $Q = k/P$.

\begin{align*}
\frac{\Delta Q/Q}{\Delta P/P} &= \frac{\Delta(\ln Q)}{\Delta(\ln P)}  \\
    &= \frac{\Delta(\ln (k/P))}{\Delta(\ln P)}  \\
    &= \frac{\Delta(\ln (k) - \ln (P))}{\Delta(\ln P)}  \\
    &= \frac{-\Delta(\ln (P))}{\Delta(\ln P)}  \\
    &= -1  \text{.}
\end{align*}

Method 2:

Here, just notice $Q = k/P$ and $\Delta Q = \Delta\left( \frac{k}{P} \right) = \frac{-k}{P^2}\Delta P$, the latter being an application of [implicit differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function#Implicit_differentiation) (with, as always, the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)).

\begin{align*}
\frac{\Delta Q/Q}{\Delta P/P} &= \frac{\frac{\frac{-k}{P^2}\Delta P}{\frac{k}{P}}}{\frac{\Delta P}{P}}  \\
    &= \frac{\frac{\frac{-k}{P^2}\Delta P}{\frac{k}{P}}\cdot \frac{P/k}{P/k}}{\frac{\Delta P}{P}}  \\
    &= \frac{\frac{-\Delta P}{P}}{\frac{\Delta P}{P}}  \\
    = -1  \text{.}
\end{align*}